# (edited) Let $(x_{n_n})$ be a sequence of positive real numbers which has no convergent subsequence. Prove lim $x_n=+\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

I know this is really pedantic and obvious, but my real analysis teacher just wants us to grasp some basic concepts. I would just like to know if this proof works, even if there is some other way, I just seek verification on mine.

Proof: Suppose $(x_{n_n})$ is a sequence of positive real numbers which has no convergent subsequence. Thus,$(x_{n_n})$ is not bounded above, which implies $\forall M\in\textbf{R}$, $\exists$ N $\in\textbf{N}$  such that $|x_n-M|>\epsilon$ => $x_{n}-M > \epsilon$ => $x_{n}> \epsilon+M$ ($\forall\epsilon>0$).Hence, $\lim x_n=+\infty$.//

Comment: Your proof is incomplete in essential ways. Why does $\lim x_n$ exist?

Comment: The negation of $\lim x_n = \infty$ is not $\lim x_n = L \in \mathbb{R}.$

Comment: The negation of $\lim x_n=\infty$ is $\exists M>0$ s.t. for each $n\in\Bbb N$ there is a $k>n$ with $x_k<M$. So you can find a bounded subsequence.

Comment: Don't use your intuitive idea of what "tends to infinity" means. Look at the formal definition, and work with it. (It may appear more cumbersome, but it is correct.)

Comment: @StefanH.is this M not the same as L. Sequences can tend to a limit without exactly being theat so x$_{k}\leq M$ or L in my case.

Comment: No, it is not the same. For one thing, there is no $L$. You wrote it, but that's just a mistake.

Comment: If there is no convergent subsequence then the sequence as a whole does not converge, so $\lim_n x_n=L$ is wrong.  The alternative to $\lim_n x_n=\infty$ in this case would be that there is no limit within $[0,\infty]$ (with closed brackets on both the left and right).

Comment: @MichaelHardy, I tried to correct my proof above. Is it getting there now, or am i still missing something?

Comment: Why does $x_n> M +\varepsilon$ hold for every $n$? To me, you first claim is too fast. I would start proving that it is not bounded. (I think you still should show this? Can be done by reductio ad absurdum). Then somehow you know that a subsequence tends to infinity (why?). Why can you conclude that the whole sequence converges to infinity (Maybe the last two steps can be done in one step)

Comment: If a sequence has no convergent subsequence,you shouldn't have to prove that its not bounded above.If it were bounded you could pick a subsequence which converged to that so called upper bound. And that statement with $x_{n}$>M+$\epsilon$ holds for all n$\geq\textbf{N}$

Comment: An unbounded sequence does not necessarily tend to infinity. Think of $a_n= n$ for odd $n$ and zero for even $n$. Of course this sequence has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: But we are already assuming that it has no convergent subsequence, so this example doesn't apply.

Comment: What is THE upper bound? Do I find a convergent subsequence against any upper bound? I would simply apply Bolzano Weierstrass which states that a bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence. Then I've found a contradiction

Comment: of course this example does not apply. But you have to prove that this does not apply. You only know that the sequence is unbounded. This means: For every $M$ there exists some $n$ such that $x_n> M$. You gain no further information!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10415/discussion-between-crypto-and-quickbeam2k1)

Answer (score 1):

(Concerning your proof: Given a sequence $\bigl(x_n\bigr)_{n\geq1}$ there is no such thing as a sequence $\bigl(x_{n_n}\bigr)_{n\geq1}$.)

A hint: Prove the contrapositive. This means the following:

Assume $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\infty$ is false.

Then there is an $M>0$ such that $\ldots$

Then there is a subsequence $\bigl(x_{n_k}\bigr)_{k\geq1}$ such that $\ldots$

Comment: M > 0 s.t x$_{n}\leq M$. Then there is a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ s.t lim $x_{n_k}$ = M. This uses every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence (B.Weierstrass).

Comment: you can't say that $x_n\to M$. Additionally, if you showed that there is no such $M$ you still need to verify that the whole sequence tends to $\infty$

Comment: I just wanted to point out that a bounded sequence does not have a subsequence that converges to its upper bound. Then I wanted to emphasize that the proof is not done after showing that "there is no such $M$". Sorry for the confusion